# How to integrate payment online method into my Android Studio app?

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway, payment, sandbox

I'm a student and I have an `Android Studio` app for my course project. I want to integrate the debit card payment feature into my app. I have tried `Paypal Sandbox` but it does not work. I found `Razorpay` but it is only available for Indian currency.

[image]

I wanna build payment for `USD` or `VNĐ`. Where I can start? Please give me a tip

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razorpay is easy to handle online debit card payment. It supports 100 currencies including USD. [https://razorpay.com/blog/best-payment-gateway-india/#:~:text=Razorpay%20is%20the%20only%20converged,UPI%2C%20and%20popular%20mobile%20wallets.e](https://razorpay.com/blog/best-payment-gateway-india/#:%7E:text=Razorpay%20is%20the%20only%20converged,UPI%2C%20and%20popular%20mobile%20wallets.e). For more information refer the former link and also this https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/

Comment: OMG. thanks for your help. i will try and give you a result